# How to update a d3.js graph inside an angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

For a personal project I am trying to dynamically update the data used to build a chart with the same features as a [well known d3.js example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3943967). However, I am not able to find the way to delete and re-draw a previous chart after the data is updated.

My code is for an angular directive that contains the d3.js graph. A summary of the directive is the following:

```
angular.module('stockchartFccApp')
.directive('linearChart', ['$window', '$timeout', 'd3Service', function ($window, $timeout, d3Service) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace:true,
        scope: {chartData: '='},
        template:"<svg width='850' height='1200'></svg>",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            d3Service.d3().then(function(d3) {
                scope.svg = null;
                scope.container = null;

                scope.render = function(data){

                    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
                     width = 480 - margin.left - margin.right,
                     height = 360 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
                     padding = 20,
                     p = [20, 50, 30, 50]; 

                    var matrix_data = dataBuilding(tickers, daterange);

                    var svg = d3.select(elem[0])
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("transform",
                        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

                    var n = matrix_data[0].length;

                    var color_range = d3.scale
                        .category10();

                    var stack = d3.layout.stack();
                    var layers = stack(matrix_data);
                    var yGroupMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer, function(d) { return d.y; }); });
                    var yStackMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; }); });

                    var x = d3.scale
                        .ordinal()
                        .domain(d3.range(max_m))
                        .rangeRoundBands([0, width - margin.right - margin.left]);




                    var y = d3.scale
                        .linear()
                        .domain([0, yStackMax])
                        .range([height, 0]);


                    var valgroup = svg.selectAll("g.valgroup")
                        .data(layers)
                        .enter()
                        .append("svg:g")
                        .attr("class", "valgroup")
                        .style("fill", function(d, i) {
                            return color_range(i);
                        })
                        .style("stroke", function(d, i) { return d3.rgb(color_range(i)).darker(); });          

                    var rect = valgroup.selectAll("rect")
                        .data(function(d){return d;})
                        .enter()
                        .append("svg:rect")
                        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
                        .attr("y", height)
                        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                        .attr("height", 0)

                    rect.transition()
                        .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 10; })
                        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
                        .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); });


                    d3.selectAll("input")
                        .on("change", change);


                    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                        d3.select("input[value=\"grouped\"]")
                        .property("checked", true)
                        .each(change);
                    }, 2000);

                    function change() {
                        clearTimeout(timeout);
                        if (this.value === "grouped") transitionGrouped();
                        else transitionStacked();
                    };

                    function rescale(yrange) {
                        //code
                    };

                    function transitionGrouped() {
                        //code
                    };

                    function transitionStacked() {
                        //code

                    };
                }

                scope.$watch('chartData', function(newVal, oldVal){
                    scope.render(newVal);
                }, true);


            });
        }
      }
   }
 ]);
```

The code exclude legends and other functions for being quite similar to those in the example or irrelevant.

With my current code my old chart get inactive and it is overlapped by a new active chart. I have tried something like below:

```
svg.selectAll("*").remove();
```

to remove the previous chart without success.

In short, my question is: how and where in code can get rid of every old chart so I can use always the new data?

The whole code and exercise I am working on can be found at my github repository, [evaristoc](https://github.com/evaristoc).

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This is a great resource for understanding the update/refresh sequence in d3js: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234. Written by the man himself. And I put this to use on a personal website (click `Stats` on the side bar): https://quickrant.com/, then click `Toggle Data` to see the refresh in action. And basically, the UPDATE function from the first link I sent is where the magic happens, as it effectively removes old elements by way of ` .remove()'. My directive is located here: https://github.com/mikechabot/quickrant-web/blob/master/src/main/webapp/js/directives/directives.js as `qrStatistic`

Comment: I think the basic problem here is that every time scope.render is called, you are appending a new SVG to the element. Your template already contains an SVG element, so the first time it's rendered you'll get 2 SVGs, then they'll just keep adding from there. (Check in the inspector.) Instead, get the existing SVG and work from there: `d3.select(elem[0]).select('svg')`

Comment: Thanks Ethan and lux! It was helpful!